# jQuery Add To Form Not Sending Value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a section in my form as follows:

```
  <div id="evchoices">
      <div class="choice">Play <input type="checkbox" name="play" checked></div>
      <div class="choice">Pause <input type="checkbox" name="pause" ></div>
      <div class="choice">Stop <input type="checkbox" name="stop"></div>
      <div class="choice">Complete <input type="checkbox" name="complete" checked></div>
  </div>
```

That works fine on it's own.  I'm using the following line of jQuery to add new elements:

```
$("#evchoices").append('<div class="choice" id="adev'+evtal+'">'+evtal+' Seconds<input name="'+evtal+'seconds" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>');
```

Where evtal is a number the user adds.  The generated source shows the following as what is added:

```
<div class="choice">1 Seconds<input name="1seconds" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
```

Which seems fine, but when the form is submitted 1seconds is not passed along.  Any ideas?

Comment: If the checkbox is not checked, it's not passed.

Comment: That's what is strange.  It displayed as checked.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but I can see that on your dynamic input the `checked` attribute has `=""` after it, which might cause problems, but shouldn't and the same goes for the input name starting with a number. Variables usually can't start with a number, but as far as I've read, this shouldn't affect HTML input field names. But if noone knows, you can try that, maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: yes, if checked, it should read checked="checked"

Answer (score 0):

Prior to HTML5, the `ID` attribute couldn't start with a number. Maybe the `name` attribute has the same problem. Try `name="seconds1"`, in place of `name="1seconds"` (as you do with `ID`. BTW: why don't we see the `ID` in the generated code?)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following code to work.  Not sure if it's the issue or not, but are you sure you're declaring the "etval" variable?

```
  $(document).ready( function() {  

    var evtal = 1;

    $("#evchoices").append('<div class="choice" id="adev' + evtal + '">' + evtal + 'Seconds<input name="' + evtal + 'seconds" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>'); 
 });
```

Play 
      Pause 
      Stop 
      Complete